# What does a function with *args mean when it is said that 'we can access any class without having to pass it into the method signature?'

Tags: python, class

I recently came across the following function: `def generic_method(self, *args)`

And I read that this means that one can access any class attributes by calling `self.attribute_name` without having to pass it into the method signature.

The full function read

```
class PacketContext:
    def __init__(self, capture_tstamp=None):
        self.capture_tstamp = capture_tstamp

def generic_method(self, *args): 
     self.context = PacketContext()
```

While I understand the first part, what does it mean by

> without having to pass it into the method signature?

Comment: That has nothing to do with `*args`. You can access attributes with `self.attribute_name` in methods normally.

Comment: Attributes *never* go in the signature. The signature specifies arguments, not attributes.

Comment: What is 'the signature'? - this is what I don't understand

Comment: Does it refer to the arguments of a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the `*args` have nothing to do with the ability to access attributes with `self.attribute_name`.

The signature of a function, so to speak is the definition of the interaface the function offers. In other words: "What do you need to pass and what do you get in return?"
Example:

```py
def foo(int i, bool b) -> bool:
   return i > 5 or b
```

Here, the signature is "Give me an `int i` and a `bool b` and I'll return a `bool`.

The `self` argument is a little special. If you add the `self` argument to a function in Python, it indicates that this is an instance method.
This means that the function requires a class to be instantiated before the method can be run on an the instance of an object.
Example:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, instance_variable):
        self.instance_variable = instance_variable

    def my_method(self, *args): 
        print(self.instance_variable)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   instance_of_my_class = MyClass(instance_variable="Great")

   # Notice how my_method is called
   instance_of_my_class.my_method()

   # Internally, Python does the following when it encounters the line above
   my_method(self=instance_of_my_class)
```

Now what they (to my understanding) mean by

> without having to pass it into the method signature?

is that you didn't have to specify `instance_variable` in the signature of `my_method`. Because it is an instance method, you can access all attributes of the instance via `self`.

Comment: Oh wow, this makes perfect sense in the context of what I am doing- thanks. Because I am trying to reference functions/attributes from inside `class MyClass` without adding extra arguments in my function!

Comment: Hi Till, can I also please kindly ask that you look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73121470/what-does-arg-and-kwargs-mean-when-when-passed-through-a-constructor